# Select rows from one tables which are not available in the second table

Tags: sql, oracle

I need a query where in I can select records in one table that are not in another table

I have 2 tables

```
TABLE 1: LOGS
TABLE 2: MASTER LIST
```

Logs = records the logs
Master list = list of all registered name.

Example:

```
LOGS
HOST | USER | NAME
==================
1    | A    | A1 
1    | A    | A1
1    | A    | A1
1    | A    | D1

MASTER
HOST | USER | NAME
===================
1    | A    | A1
1    | A    | B1
1    | A    | C1
```

Result should be:

```
HOST | USER | NAME
==================
1    | A    | D1
```

Select the row which name is not included in the Table 2: Masterlist.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
select * from table1 
where not exists
(
  select host, user, name
  from table2
  where table2.host = table1.host and 
        table2.user = table1.user and 
        table2.name = table1.name
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use `LEFT JOIN` like this:

```
   SELECT L.* 
     FROM Logs L
LEFT JOIN Master M
       ON L.Name = M.Name
     WHERE M.Name IS NULL
```

Result:

```
╔══════╦══════╦══════╗
║ HOST ║ USER ║ NAME ║
╠══════╬══════╬══════╣
║    1 ║ A    ║ D1   ║
╚══════╩══════╩══════╝
```

Here `WHERE M.Name IS NULL` excludes all records which are common in both tables.

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/85796/7)